# Use javaOptions from build.sbt during runtime

Tags: playframework, sbt

I've put some javaOptions in build.sbt which are used while running tests. These are working as expected.

```
javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/test.conf"
javaOptions in Test += "-Duser.timezone=UTC"
```

I want to use something similar during runtime as well. I've tried the following and they don't work at all:

```
javaOptions in Runtime += "-Duser.timezone=UTC"
javaOptions in run += "-Duser.timezone=UTC"
```

I'm running the tests/application from command line using "**activator test**" and "**activator run**". 
Since the javaOptions are not working, the only other option is to pass them in the command line as: "**activator run -Duser.timezone=UTC**". I prefer not passing the command line arguments.

Comment: Did you try without mentioning anything like `javaOptions += "-Duser.timezone=UTC"`?

Answer (score 7):

`javaOptions` are only applied to a forked JVM.

```
> help javaOptions
Options passed to a new JVM when forking.
```

The reason why it is working in your tests is that Playframework by default runs your test in a forked JVM in parallel.

```
> show test:fork
[info] true
```

If you want to achieve this for the run task as well you can use a forked JVM as well. Add the following to `build.sbt` file:

```
 fork in run := true
```

See chapter on Forking in SBT documentation for further details: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Forking.html